# Add an html snippet some within body of the theme using preprocess

Tags: 7, theming

I want to add a small html within the body tag of the site. I believe I can use template preprocess for this. I don't want to touch the template files. I am doing this from a module.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't want to touch the page.tpl.php? If you mind about changing the original theme you can create a subtheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add [hook_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) into your module. See the given example on how to add HTML markup.

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  $node->content['my_additional_field'] = array(
    '#markup' => $additional_field, 
    '#weight' => 10, 
    '#theme' => 'mymodule_my_additional_field',
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`hook_preprocess_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) for that:

```
MODULENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // …
}
```